# Restore firmware on machine without MacOS

Tags: macbook-pro, firmware, flash-memory

My daughter's Macbook Air is broken.  She's a wild non-child and its likely to have been roughly treated and also left for years without charge, not updated (I told her!) and used on virus'y sites.

Appearance is there is no internal flash.  All attempts to recover and install El Capitan to an external USB stick fail with some kind of firmware issue. I run a Macbook with Sierra and a clone of that will boot her machine.  I've tried building an install usb for Catalina (which it should run) but that won't work - I either get errors about the fs type (note I've tried MacOS extended (journaled) and apfs or it complains about a missing firmware partition. I've not yet tried building an install stick for El Capitan (assuming I can get El Capitan from the app store) - about to try that next.

Its perfectly possibly that the internal flash is fried and I won't get anywhere.  Aside from that, is it possible that the firmware is fried and that is preventing access to the internal storage ?  I know little about boot ROMs and boot partitions and BIOS's on apple though I used to run many linuxes. Other than visiting the Apple store can someone suggest a way forwards ?

Ideally it would be great to find a way to install the firmware needed and find out that "wow, the internal storage still is there and works" and install a MacOS to it (preferably Catalina).  Failing that it would be nice to make it usable booting from a minimal external usb stick - I can't build one by cloning without buying some large storage as my systems on my Macbook are a very long way from fitting on a cheap stick (I'm just about to put a 2Tb drive in to ensure I don't go too close to full on 1Tb).

Is it Facked or is there a way forwards other than a big external drive?

Here is an image of what system report says:

[image: System Report top bit]

Comment: Other users have had issues with firmware with respect to installing Catalina. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379944/updating-to-macos-catalina-gets-stuck-when-trying-to-update-from-os-x-mavericks) for example.